# System.InvalidOperationException: Missing parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I try to send parameter to asmx(web service file) but i get error about "System.InvalidOperationException: Missing parameter". Please help me to solve this problem and thank you so much

this is my ajax function

```
$("#dd_address").change(function () {

            var rowID = $(this).find(':selected').val();
            console.log(rowID);
            $.ajax({
                url: "WebService.asmx/queryCity",

                data: {
                    id: JSON.stringify(rowID),                        
                },
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
                success: OnSuccess,
                error: OnError
            });
        });
```

this is my code from asmx

```
 DataTable result;

    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string queryCity(string id)
    {

        DataTable dt;
        SqlConnection MRK_Conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=192.168.24.30;Initial Catalog=Marketing_Data;Persist Security info=True;User ID=sa;Password=sa");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader sql_dr;
        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

        MRK_Conn.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("select [City RowID], [City Description] from City where [Des Ref Province] = '" + id + "'", MRK_Conn);
        dt = new DataTable();
        sql_dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dt.Load(sql_dr);
        sql_dr.Close();
        MRK_Conn.Close();
        result = dt;

        return serializer.Serialize(result);
    }
```

and in web config file

```
  <webServices>
    <protocols>
      <add name="HttpGet"/>
      <add name="HttpPost"/>
    </protocols>
  </webServices>
```

Comment: This is vulnerable to sql injection and you should look into changing the query to SqlCommand + Parameters at the least

Comment: But the error Missing parameter it means parameter from ajax not send to asmx. right or not ?

Answer (score 1):

Problem in your code is in the way you are passing the input parameter to the method, change it like this:-

```
var rowID = { "id" : $(this).find(':selected').val() };
```

Then, pass it like this in the method:-

```
data : JSON.stringify(rowID)
```

Apart from this your ADO.NET code is open for [SQL Injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) attack, so please use parametrized query instead.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your code, below code works for me. Please remember I have hardcoded `var rowID = 20;` make your changes as you need.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

**ASPX Page button:**

```
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="sendrequest();" />
```

**Javascript "sendrequest" Function:**

```
<script>
    function sendrequest()
    {
        var rowID = 20;
        console.log(rowID);
        $.ajax({
            url: "WebService.asmx/queryCity",
            data: '{"id":"' + rowID + '"}',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(data.d);
                var xml = $(xmlDoc);
                var city = xml.find("Table1");
                alert(city.text());
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert('error: ' + xhr.status + ' ' + thrownError);
            }
        });

    }
</script>
```

**Webservice Method:**

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string queryCity(string id)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt= new DataTable("Table");
    SqlConnection MRK_Conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=KEVAL;Initial Catalog=SampleDatabase;Persist Security info=True;User ID=sa;Password=sa123");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataReader sql_dr;
    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

    MRK_Conn.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("select [City RowID], [City Description] from City where [Des Ref Province] = '" + id + "'", MRK_Conn);
    dt = new DataTable();
    sql_dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    dt.Load(sql_dr);
    sql_dr.Close();
    MRK_Conn.Close();
    ds.Tables.Add(dt);

    return ds.GetXml();
}
```