# System.InvalidOperationException: Parameter: Not Found

Tags: c#

I am trying to redirect a page to another page sample `Login.html to Index.html`. but after the execution of the redirect code. this error occurs `System.InvalidOperationException: Parameter: users not found`. I searched for a solution on this site, like this solution. [System.InvalidOperationException: Missing parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29373340/system-invalidoperationexception-missing-parameter)
but it can't helped.
This is my code.

```
   [WebMethod]
    public void LogMeIn(string users, string pass) {

        try
        {
            string stmt = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbllogin WHERE userName = '" + users + "' AND passWord ='" + pass + "'";
            int count = 0;

            using (MySqlConnection thisConnection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString()))
            {
                using (MySqlCommand cmdCount = new MySqlCommand(stmt, thisConnection))
                {
                    thisConnection.Open();
                    count = Convert.ToInt32(cmdCount.ExecuteScalar());
                    if (count > 0)
                    {
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/default/index.htm", true);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException tEx)
        {
            // Do nothing. ASP.NET is redirecting.
            // Always comment this so other developers know why the exception 
            // is being swallowed.
            Console.WriteLine(tEx.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log other types of exception.
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

And in WebConfig. i don't know if the location Path = "WebService" is Correct.

```
<location path="WebService">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

EDITS: JAVASCRIPT

```
function LoginMeIn(username, password) {
    var xdata = "{'users':'" + username.toString()
              + "','pass':'" + password.toString()
              + "'}";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '../WebService/userLogin.asmx/LogMeIn',
        data: xdata,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {

        },
        error: function (e) {
           // $("#divResult").html("Something Wrong.");
        }
    });
}
```

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: How are you calling the webmethod? GET? POST? JSON?

Comment: @DStanley I call it using javascript sir, using POST. I will attached the code of javascript. please see.

Comment: Shouldn’t the condition be count > 0 ?

Comment: You should sanitize your code: remove sql injection with parameters https://bobby-tables.com/ and DON'T store passwords plaintext

Comment: @AccessDenied I will do it right away sir after this problem. I hope you could help me

Comment: @AccessDenied, yes Sir. I did try that and it works, but the main problem still exist.